# How Can I Make table with different number of rows - C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need any hints to help me how to apply this idea, first of all I want to do table contain a column is about week's days, it will be bind from database, maybe all days of the week or some days.
Each day has maybe one or two rows, according to the user needs, and each row has 4 columns it is fixed number, it will not change.
For example, I enter to my account, I found from Saturday to Monday in my table, each Day has one row as default, this row has 4 columns. If I want to fill Saturday I have two periods not one period, so I have to have plus button if I click on it there is a new row will be add to fill the second period, and if I save my work these two rows will related to Saturday as I added.
I hope you Understand what I want, I use C# , ASP.NET & SQL Server.

Comment: You need to make the requirements clearer

Comment: Can you show use what you have tried so far